# Significance of the woman on the TV being interviewed

Tags: analysis, dc-extended-universe, justice-league

In the 2017 movie *Justice League*, we see an interview take place with an older woman proclaiming that her husband was kidnapped by aliens.  This didn't seem directly related to the plot in any way and never came back as important.  We also never see this woman again.

Why was this included?  What is its significance?

Answer (score 24):

If I remember correctly, the woman being interviewed was the wife of the janitor working at Star Labs, who was kidnapped by Parademons in order to be questioned by Steppenwolf about the location of the Mother Boxes. While we never see the woman again, we do see the janitor again - when Flash, Wonder Woman and Batman find Steppenwolf's lair under Gotham harbour, he's being interrogated about the Mother Boxes.

Comment: As someone who has neither kept up with the DC TV/film universe and has not seen *Justice League*, the first sentence of this answer is baffling.

Comment: @EngineerToast I wouldn't worry too much, it's pretty nonsensical in the film itself too.

Comment: Wow. When you haven't seen the movie, this answer sounds like '70s drug-induced acid rock lyrics.

Comment: @EngineerToast I've seen most the animated series and films from the 90s and 2000s and the DC Universe animated films. I still have no idea who Steppenwolf is, even though I know everything else mentioned in this answer.

Comment: Yes, she was the janitor's wife.  I think we should take three things from the scene: (a) It establishes that the janitor was kidnapped (we see him later); (b) it sets up the subplot where people are wondering if the Parademons are Batman, i.e. that Batman has gone bad somehow; (c) there's a little bit of humor to it, she comes off as crazy and she says crazy things.

Answer (score 7):

It was to suggest that Parademon are made from human bodies like its comics counterpart.

> It is revealed in New 52 that the Parademon hordes are either remolded lifeforms or the processed corpses of which that Darkseid and Apokolips have harvested and processed from the various worlds and realities they've conquered - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parademon) .

Same thing we see in animated film [Justice League: War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League:_War) too.

And in first age of heroes flashback we do see a man getting converted into Parademon.